# Multi-thread java app vs. individual tasks execution using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, java, multi-threaded

I have a java app that runs many different threads (not always dependent on each other) using `ScheduledThreadPoolExacutor`.

I was wondering if it will have any effect (good hopefully) on the system (LINUX) if i will create separate executable jar files for each thread and run them individually in a loop using a bash script.

Does it even matter? Will it affect on the system, for bad or worse? Should i just leave it as a multi threaded application in java?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would imagine it would have the opposite of the desire effect due to the overheads of loading bash and multiple copies of what would otherwise be common memory structures.

Comment: You'll be running multiple JVMs...